# error in Showing multiple locations in google map in android framework

Tags: android, cordova, cross-platform, android-maps

Hello All,
I am developing an android phonegap application in which I have to show multiple locations in Google map in android emulator, I am trying sample code shown on

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.6.0/cordova_geolocation_geolocation.md.html#geolocation.getCurrentPosition

for getting current location.But its not showing current location. Can anyone guide me for this?

Thanks in advance
Tushar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check your application on device. Deploy it on your device & start GPS it will surly show current location. Emulator doesn't show current location until you gave it using DDMS tool so best way to check maps in device.

Comment: @sandeep...i checked on device,,,,,,it not showing currentlocation.Its only showing message in the emulator.....getting location......what to do for this....